# Feature while asking questions

Tags: feature-request

Currently, while asking any question on SE, you get suggestions from already existing questions. Is it good idea to show user quick wikipedia or google results for same query ? As I noticed, many user ask questions which are first result of quick google search !

Comment: Interesting idea. Might be a little hard to implement but eventually using "google automatic boxes" could be interesting. This question is of course not specific to Biology.SE. I suppose that it would be more strategic to ask the question on [Meta.StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).